# add license to installer using javapackager

Tags: java, packaging

i am using javapackager to create windows installer and can not figure out where to place the license file.the instructions are:

licenseFile=path
Location of the End User License Agreement (EULA) to be presented or recorded by the bundler. The path is relative to the packaged application resources.

i keep getting error:  Specified license file is missing.
i have made a sample .rtf file and have placed it different locations in order to get the command to work but so far not yet.

my process is:

- build in Netbeans.
- create one jar file using package for store
- sign the jar file
- use the jar file with javapackager (javapackager -deploy -native exe...ect)

Comment: Has the following `-BlicenseFile=<path_to_EULA>` worked?

Comment: do you still need an answer or you dont care now :)

Answer (score 1):

In order to add the licenseFile you shoulde:

put the name of the file:

-BlicenseFile=COPYING.txt

put the src files directory:

-srcdir

put the src files list including the licenseFile:

-srcfiles some_jar.jar;COPYING.txt;